# Did Sandburg acknowledge Twain's influence?

Tags: mark-twain, carl-sandburg

In 1886, Mark Twain wrote an essay entitled "The New Dynasty"

Its theme, and much of its language, are quite similar to Carl Sandburg's poem "I Am the People, the Mob" of half a century later.

It is plain to me that Sandburg read Twain's essay, and was inspired by its thought process and even some of its wording.

Did he ever acknowledge the role that Twain's essay played in his writing that poem?